# How to handle an optional value in a for-comp when dealing with Futures

Tags: scala

I have a for compr that looks like:

```
for {
  user <- getFutureUser(1) // Future[User]
  account <- getFutureAccount(1) // Future[Account]
  historyOpt <- ???
 } yield Wrapper(user, account, historyOpt)

case class Wrapper(user: User, account: Account, historyOpt: Option[History])
```

I am stuck on how to handle the historyOpt value.
I have a method to get the history:

```
def getHistory(id: Int): Future[History]
```

But this is based on the user, if user.getHistory is true, then I return it, otherwise it is None.

I tried this but it is wrong:

```
for {
  user <- getFutureUser(1) // Future[User]
  account <- getFutureAccount(1) // Future[Account]
  historyOpt <- if(user.getHistory) getFutureHistory(1) else Future.successful(None)
 } yield Wrapper(user, account, historyOpt)
```

**How can I handle this scenerio?**

Comment: What's the type of `Wrapper`'s third parameter? `History` or `Option[History]`?

Comment: It is Option[History]

Comment: Are you using Scalaz by any chance? I've recently been reading up on Monad Transformers and sounds like it might help your case: https://www.47deg.com/blog/fp-for-the-average-joe-part-2-scalaz-monad-transformers/

Comment: Can't delete my previous comment. I reread the question and monad transformers doesn't seem to fit the bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer:

```scala
case class User(getHistory: Boolean)
case class Account()
case class History()

def getFutureUser(x: Int): Future[User] = ???
def getFutureAccount(x: Int): Future[Account] = ???
def getFutureHistory(x: Int): Future[History] = ???

case class Wrapper(user: User, account: Account, historyOpt: Option[History])

val a: Future[Wrapper] = for {
  user <- getFutureUser(1) // Future[User]
  account <- getFutureAccount(1) // Future[Account]
  historyOpt <- if(user.getHistory) getFutureHistory(1).map(Some.apply) else Future.successful(None)
} yield Wrapper(user, account, historyOpt)
```

Comment: I'm getting a Future[Any]

Comment: @Blankman I have posted the full code snippet, please try again and post the error the compiler gives you.

Comment: Thanks your code works, mine doesn't.  Trying to figure out why!

Comment: Very strange, my code is giving me this: ```error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Any]
[error]  required: Option[?]
```

Comment: Can you please post the full snippet that trigger the compilation error?